# Not able to read data from excel as it is seen on desktop

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I am working on an `excel workbook`. I am using `python` script for operating on the `workbook`. But there two issues:

1) There are some cells which have `integer` values. When I am reading that values and putting the read value into a report file (`.txt`), it is appending `.0` with the number. Eg. if there is value 6, it is giving 6.0 when it is not supposed to do this. I have read that there is nothing as `integer` in excel. Still, I have 1000s of parameters and thus, I cant convert directly all of them to `integer` using some `python` function because that may convert values which are actually `float` also.

2) And when I am reading `boolean` TRUE and FALSE, it is giving me 1 and 0. I want to get whatever `text` I see in the excel workbook on my desktop. I don't want any conversions like that. 

I am using `xlrd` for `excel` operations in `python`.

Please tell me what I should do to solve this problem? 
Note: My excel sheet contains more than 100 sheets and I can't modify "true or false" with "1 and 0" etc

Comment: For 1, format your values to lose the 0 prior to writing them to the text file. For 2, boolean True is most probably 1. Just put a condition wherein `if 1 then write True, else write False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlrd` is giving you all your numbers as floats, and your booleans as integers. How you print them out is purely a python matter.

I'll asume you already know which cells contain boolean values. (If you don't,  check the cell's `ctype` as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244650/699305) by Massimo Fuccillo-- see @JohnY's comment below for details.) You can print boolean cells as `True` and `False` by simply printing `bool(var)` instead of `var`:

```
>>> var = 1
>>> print bool(var)
True
```

When writing to a file this will be output as the string `'True'` (resp. `'False'`), as intended.

Since Excel does not distinguish between ints and floats, we'll assume that by `integer` you mean any number whose fractional part is zero. When python prints a float it adds `.0` to preserve the information that it is a float.

The simplest solution would be to suppress this if you format your numbers for output with "%g":

```
>>> "%g" % 6.0
'6'
```

However, `"%g"` will round real numbers to six significant digits by default (though you can specify a different precision).

```
>>> "%g" % 2500.03
'2500.03'
>>> "%g" % 2500.003
'2500'
```

So it's safer if you detect integral values yourself, and print them out accordingly:

```
if int(var) == var:
    print int(var)
else:
    print var
```

I recommend doing it this way.

Comment: Though Excel doesn't differentiate between integers and floats, xlrd is smart enough to figure out when 1.0 or 0.0 in Excel is meant as a Boolean. There are two ways that xlrd tells you a cell is Boolean. One is the `ctype`, which is covered by the answer from Massimo Fuccillo. The other way is that xlrd actually returns a **Python integer** for Excel Booleans, whereas it returns a **Python float** for regular Excel numbers. Thus the second way to tell the difference is to use `isinstance()` on the value. But checking `ctype` is the preferred and more self-documenting way.

Answer (score 3):

for the boolean question you can test ctype:

```
for rx in range(ws.nrows):
        for cx in range(ws.ncols):
            print ws.cell(rx,cx).value, ws.cell(rx,cx).ctype
```

if the excel original cell is "TRUE" FALSE" the ctype value is 4

Comment: It may be `4`, but it'd be better to compare it to the `xlrd.XL_CELL_BOOLEAN` constant which is much clearer as to intent...

Comment: This fails to address either of OP's questions. How can checking the CType help him with the second issue? He knows it's already boolean, he just wants to output True when it shows True and output False otherwise, instead of their binary equivalent.

Comment: from xlrd documentation:  XL_CELL_BOOLEAN 1 means TRUE, 0 means FALSE.